# How to add sourcemaps to GraalVM JS inspection?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium, graalvm

The following code executes a javascript code snippet on GraalVM Javascript engine:

```
 try (Context context = Context.newBuilder("js").option("inspect", "4444").build()) {
        Value hello = context.eval(Source.newBuilder("js", "some minified javascript", "sample.js").build());

      // E.g.: Sleep a bit so I can open the debugger in chrome and start debugging
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How can I attach a sourcemap to this minified javascript?

I tried to add the following to the end of the minified javascript, but port 8080 was not even pinged:

```
//# sourceMappingUrl=http://localhost:8080/sample.map
```

Also, if I right click on the developer window and choose *Add source map...*, the URL I enter is not downloaded (I checked it by implementing a sample servlet on that port that logs every network request).

Please note that I am opening the debugger in the way that the script runs on the JVM and I connect to it by enter a URL in chrome like this:

```
devtools://devtools/bundled/js_app.html?ws=127.0.0.1:4444/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's supposed to work as usual.

As far as I know there's no current way to specify the source maps through an API.

However the `//#sourceMappingUrl=` comment works (note your comment lacks the `Url` part).

Here's an example on a sample typescript file:

```
declare var myClass: any;

interface Pointlike {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}
interface Named {
  name: string;
}
 
function logPoint(point: Pointlike) {
  console.log("x = " + point.x + ", y = " + point.y);
}
 
function logName(x: Named) {
  console.log("Hello, " + x.name);
}
 
const obj = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  name: "Origin",
};
 
logPoint(obj);
logName(obj);

console.log("0: " + myClass.id);
console.log("1: " + myClass.text);
console.log("2: " + myClass.arr[1]);
console.log("3: " + myClass.ret42());

console.log("Done");
```

and the tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "outDir": "out",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "rootDir": "."
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "resources"
    ]
}
```

and the java file `Main.java`:

```
import org.graalvm.polyglot.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Main { 
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
      File file = new File("out/logpoints.js");

      String language = Source.findLanguage(file);
      Source source = Source.newBuilder(language, file)
                            .build();
      try (Context context = Context.newBuilder("js")
             .allowAllAccess(true)
             .option("inspect", "4444")
             .build()) {
        context.getBindings("js")
               .putMember("myClass", new MyClass());
        Value hello = context.eval(source);
    } 
  }
  
  public static class MyClass {
      public int               id    = 42;
      public String            text  = "42";
      public int[]             arr   = new int[]{1, 42, 3};
      public Callable<Integer> ret42 = () -> 42;
  }  
}
```

Compile the ts file, in the **main** dir run the `tsc` with no arguments:

```
tsc
```

Open `out/logpoints.js` and change the sourceMappingUrl to point to http instead of the relative path on the local fs as generated by the ts compiler:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=http://localhost:8000/out/logpoints.js.map
```

In the **main** dir run the python server:

```
> python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000

Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

Run the java file:

```
$ javac Main 
java Main
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:4444/Nh_8EndzB0jCaOfA1giEpld5C1ilx5OeyWbmA3zFDEc
For help, see: https://www.graalvm.org/docs/tools/chrome-debugger
E.g. in Chrome open: devtools://devtools/bundled/js_app.html?ws=127.0.0.1:4444/Nh_8EndzB0jCaOfA1giEpld5C1ilx5OeyWbmA3zFDEc
```

Open the `devtools` url in Chrome. It should open the js file and the typescript file obtained through the sourceMapping. And the breakpoints and stepping through works on the typescript file.

[image: debugger with sourcemap through http]

You can even pass Java objects through the bindings and inspect them both in console and in the 'Local' tab in the debugger:

[image: Java objects in the debugger]

Comment: In my source code it is sourceMappingUrl. It was my copy-paste issue. Let me check your response in reality. However, on the screenshot I see the compiled javascript file, not the original typescript file that should be shown if sourcemap is resolved. Also, I am wondering how the filesystem is shown on the left side. Is this a chrome opened with a link like devtools://... ?

Comment: I made the question cleaner, how I open the developer toolbar. If there is other option to open it via link and in the way that source maps work, I would be truly appreciated to get info about it.

Comment: Yes the debugger operates on the typescript file. I added a few screenshots to the answer. 1 showing debugger in the ts file and another showing that http url works too.

Comment: Yes the filesystem showed is there because I added the folder to the workspace using the add folder to the workspace link above the filesystem view. It works without it too, the js file and the resolved ts file are working.

Comment: Are you sure you are not debugging simply the js file simply as it was opened directly in the browser? The goal of GraalVM to run js files is to execute backend logic. E.g.: Call java functions from the javascript/typescript. E.g.: Drop in a variable via the GraalVM Context bindings. Is that variable accessible during debugging? If it is accessible, I am sorry and I really need information how you connected to the graalvm context for debugging.

Comment: Yes, I run the java program which runs the JS through the context, which has the inspect option set. I added steps how I run all these. The JS is generated from typescript and the context only operates on the JS file. Can you please clarify what doesn't work for you regarding calling java functions or accessing variables via the bindings?

Comment: I believe you, but I cannot reproduce it. Can you, please, add a command like this to your Java source: context.getBindings("js").putMember("helloVar", "Hello world");, and attach a screenshot where the typescript file is opened (not the js like now), the debugger stands on global variable helloVar and it shows its value coming from the GraalVM context? As an extra, without additional settings like (adding filesystem folder) in the browser. If I see this, I will accept your answer then and look for the problem on my computer.

Comment: added a screenshot with accessing java object passed through bindings, can be inspected in console too. Note that for accessing java objects you need to configure context with enough access, see Host Interoperability here: https://www.graalvm.org/sdk/javadoc/org/graalvm/polyglot/Context.html I used                           .allowAllAccess(true) for this example. If MyClass can't be accessed `myclass.id` and others will be `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Strange thing is that I did these things, knew about access stuff and all. And still not even a ping to the sourcemap. I guess I will try finding what is wrong with my setup (maybe GraalVM version, Chrome version or just a typo that I cannot see). But as I see it works for others, I know that the problem is somewhere on my side. Sorry for being suspicious.